# Crash when trying to set pageloadtimeout in Selenium 3.6

Tags: selenium, firefox, automation, geckodriver

I am trying to upgrade my project from Selenium 3.0.0beta4 to 3.6.0. I want to set the timeout for page loading with

```
driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(90, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

This, however, crashes the application:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.InvalidArgumentException: 
Build info: version: '3.6.0', revision: '6fbf3ec767', time: '2017-09-27T16:15:26.402Z'
System info: host: 'machine.example.org', ip: '127.0.0.1', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '4.4.88', java.version: '1.8.0_144'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
Capabilities [{moz:profile=/tmp/rust_mozprofile.AZHGaB47hL8x, rotatable=false, timeouts={implicit=0, page load=300000, script=30000}, pageLoadStrategy=normal, platform=LINUX, specificationLevel=0, moz:accessibilityChecks=false, acceptInsecureCerts=true, browserVersion=52.4.0, platformVersion=4.4.88, moz:processID=10959, browserName=firefox, javascriptEnabled=true, platformName=LINUX}]
```

The value is not changed. I am using geckodriver v0.18.0 and Firefox 52.4.0.
Is there any limitation on the Firefox version I can use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Selenium 3.0.0beta4 version of my application I set the following property for the gecko driver:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "/path/to/geckodriver");
```

After I changed the property to

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.marionette", "/path/to/geckodriver");
```

in the Selenium 3.6.0 version my application started working again. I use Firefox v45.9.0 and geckodriver v0.18.0. Other combinations may work, too.